# Why doesn't x Rigidbody2D.velocity change, although y does?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a code to push an enemy (using Rigidbody2D.velocity) when the object which contains the script and which is trigger collides with an enemy. And to push it in other direction if player.transform.position.x is higher than enemy's.  But x velocity didn't change, although y did. AddForce() worked, but it has a different effect, so I need velocity.
Here is the code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == enemyTag)
        {
            if (enemy.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                enemyRB.velocity = new Vector2(30, 0);
            }
            else { enemyRB.velocity = new Vector2(-30f, 0f); }
        }
    }
```

I replaced velocity with position to check if any of Rigidbody components work properly, like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == enemyTag)
        {
            if (enemy.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                enemyRB.position = new Vector2(30, 0);
            }
            else { enemyRB.position = new Vector2(-30f, 0f); }
        }
    }
```

And it worked, but with velocity it doesn't. I also tried to make the velocity bigger, so that I would know if it is strong enough, but it didn't help, as well as reloading the computer. What might the problem be in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Unity's physics engine, you cannot set the velocity of a kinematic Rigidbody directly - [it's hidden right at the bottom of the velocity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20A%20velocity%20in%20Unity,and%20will%20have%20no%20effect.).

You could either: make your Rigidbody component non-kinematic, but this would completely pull it from the physics simulation; or use the AddForce function with ForceMode.VelocityChange to ignore the mass of your object.